# Calculating Probabilities

Tags: python, performance

This code calculates the probability of a runner finishing 3rd and it works like expected. I'm pretty sure though that is woefully inefficient. How could this code be transformed in a much more cleaner and performance efficient way?
My focus is the nested fors and and the if handlings.

```
def Trd(mylist=[]):

    third=[]
    for thirds in range(len(mylist)):
        sum=0
        for seconds in range(len(mylist)):
           sum_first=0
           if seconds==thirds:
               pass
           else:
               for firsts in range(len(mylist)):
                   if firsts==thirds:
                       pass
                   elif firsts==seconds:
                       pass
                   else:
                       frsts=mylist[firsts]*(mylist[seconds]/(1-mylist[firsts]))*(mylist[thirds]/(1-mylist[firsts]-mylist[seconds]))
                       sum_first+=frsts
           sum+=sum_first
        third.append(sum)  
    print(third)

list=[0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1]
Trd(list)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!